# Insert jQuery and JavaScript into HTML programatically in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

Have seen this code but I am not able to run it properly.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     _webview.delegate = self;
     [_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                                      pathForResource:@"Samplehtml" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     NSString *jsFile = @"jquery-1.11.0";
     NSString *jsFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:jsFile ofType:@"js"];
     NSURL *jsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:jsFilePath];
     NSString *javascriptCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsURL.path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
     [_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascriptCode];   
}
```

So this is what i am trying.

**MyJavaScript.js**

```
$("p").click(function() {
alert("hello");
```

})

Samplehtml.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>

    <p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Check that you getting file path or not?

Comment: Yes i'm getting the path for jsFile. I want to know how this js would be working when I'm opening my html page. The code i'm using to open html is NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];

Comment: i am talking about `jsFile` this file

Comment: Yes m getting jsFilePath.

Comment: you have file `jquery-1.11.0` in your project?

Comment: Yes i have this file in my project.

Comment: Your code is right. Can you say what problem you are currently facing?

Comment: Actually i'm unable to figure it out, how to run this code. I have one html, js, jquery and i have made one function written above. I want to know how do i open my html that this js will work. I'm working on ePub reader. It unzips while opening, so cannot be able to edit xhtml and want to add js or jquery programatically so my js functionalities will work in xhtml.

Comment: Post your full code so i can understand what you have done?

Comment: Where can i post? it is not allowing me put my code here. Can i get your email id or anything by which i can contact you!

Comment: Edit your question and add code in question.

Comment: Ok editing my code

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala pls respond!

Comment: I am working on it.

Comment: can you give me your sample.html and js file? Because my side it is working

Comment: script.js is missing

Comment: You only have this 4 line in your `.html` file are you sure.

Comment: Actually the point is to check that will i'm able to use java script or not. Thats y i have taken sample html for testing purposes.

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala if am able to get the alert while opening html. Then i can add my highlights features easily. So all i'm requesting you is pls guide me by which i'm able to use js in my html in iOS app

Comment: your alert is inside your .js file. Which means you have added the js file

Comment: Alert is in js for testing. Is this working on app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this. It is working on my side

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Samplehtml" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString *htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
}
```

After that inside your `webViewDidFinishLoad`

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     NSString *jsFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"simple" ofType:@"js"];
     NSURL *jsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:jsFilePath];
     NSString *javascriptCode1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
     jsFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"simple2" ofType:@"js"];
     jsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:jsFilePath];
     NSString *javascriptCode2 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
     [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",javascriptCode1, javascriptCode2]];
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You have one or two `js` file?

Comment: I have two js files. one for jquery and other is for alert.

Comment: Then you need to add both the content of file in single string

Comment: Its not working here bro! Can u pls send my your code which is working on my email.

Comment: I have tried your updated code too. Still in app no alert is pop up. Is it working in your code?

Comment: I have two js in MyJavaScipt.js i have $("p").click(function(){alert("hello");})
selectionEndTimeout = null; And other js is jquery-1.11.0.js which i got it from net

Comment: You doesn't give me the whole 3 file so i used my sample file. It is working on my side. Have you change the name of file in your code?

Comment: Yes i did. That's y i'm asking can u pls send the code on my email.

Comment: Have you made any changes in HTML?

Comment: I dont' have used your html and js file. It is just simple one `html` and 2 `js` file. I already write whole my code that i have used.

Comment: Instead of jsURL.path we have to replace jsFilePath, then its working perfectly. Pls edit the code. Thanks of your help :)